# Jackson management for very large JSONs in Java

Tags: java, json, performance, jackson

So what I have is a very large JSON file (600MB), and I have a few modules in my Java project that import each item in the JSON file and write it's properties to  several tables in a huge database. It works perfectly for relatively small JSON files which I had to deal with until now but this one  makes the JVM throw OutOfMemoryException.
 The library I use is Jackson and I load each item in the JSON file in a Java list in the following function:

```java
  public List<Products> listOfProducts(String JSONString)
  throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
byte[] latin1 = JSONString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String fromUtf8Bytes = new String(latin1);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Products[] productsArray = mapper.readValue(fromUtf8Bytes,
    Products[].class);

List<Products> productsList= Arrays.asList(productsArray);

return productsList;
```

}

Then the returned list is passed on to my importing functions, but before that happens the out of memory exception occurs.
Any ideas on how I can process such a large file without breaking the original JSON into several smaller ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions, boiling down to incremental processing or caching (it depends on what you want to do with your `productList`), but the simplest solution in this case is by far: **buy more RAM and increase the max JVM heap size**. For this amount of additional memory overhead, the required additional RAM is probably cheaper than the developer's time.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I already tried that. In the run configurations for that specific class I've added this 
-Xms1536m -Xmx2536m
However, when I run the program I get "Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
"
I am running on a 64bit windows 7 machine with 8GBs of RAM

Comment: @user2385870 : what VM are you using? What does `java -version` output?

Comment: It said I was using the 64bit version but for some reason my IDE was using the 32bit JRE... I managed to increase the heap size to 5GBs now, thanks for helping me look in the right direction!

Comment: @user2385870 : yeah, I confess of the question being loaded, since it sounded exactly like a 32-bit JVM being used, and you're welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

With the streaming API of Jackson, you can parse the file without having it completely in memory. Parse each Product and put it in your DB (or a few products at the same time, will probably be better for the DB overhead), but don't try to load all at once.